# file upload with php short tags

Tags: php, php-5.3

I have a code below that works with `<?=` but not `<?` or `<?php`

```
<?= $form->create('Upload', array('type'=>'file')); ?>
<?= $form->input('file', array('type'=>'file')); ?>
```

what does `<?=` do

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php echo $form->create('Upload', array('type' => 'file')); ?>
```

is equivalent to

```
<?= $form->create('Upload', array('type' => 'file')); ?>
```

.

Comment: You could even omit the last semicolon =)

Answer (score 2):

`<?=` is identical to `<? echo`

Answer (score 1):

`<?=` prints out the result of the statement. So instead of having to use `<? echo $varname; ?>` you can just do `<?= $varname ?>`